# WCF Service End Point Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-config, wcf-binding

i have deployed my wcf service on IIS.. Its giving me this error when I want to access its one of method "EndPoint Not Found" While locally its working fine for me and returning me data.

Here is my Web.config Bindings Information

```
 <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="RTAService" behaviorConfiguration="WtfServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wtfSslBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpBehaviour" contract="IRTAService" />
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IRTAService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"  />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wtfSslBinding" />
        <binding name="streamedBinding"
                 maxBufferSize="65536"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000"
                 transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="500000000"
         maxArrayLength="500000000" maxBytesPerRead="500000000"
         maxNameTableCharCount="500000000" maxStringContentLength="500000000"/>
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>

      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHttpBehaviour">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"
            automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WtfServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Please tell me any work around for that.

Comment: do you have multiple web.config files in your solution?

Comment: What is your web server settings (in terms of SSL)?  Is that wtfSslBinding supposed to be providing SSL?

Comment: Please share the actual error message you are getting.

Comment: @bluefeet: I dont have multiple webconfigs

Comment: @dtryon: I dont have ssl configured for my server right now.

Comment: @Moussa: This is the actual error "Endpoint not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see endpoint defined any where . Your config should have something like this.`

```
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:57800/Services.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServices"     contract="MYServices.IServices"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IServices" />
```

Comment: I think it is there, right under `<service name="RTAService"`

Comment: Oh .. Sorry I totally missed that part. Try one thing if you can here. Try to call the service from the same machine that you are deploying service on . Reason why i am saying this it looks to me some how firewall issue since its working on your local machine . Check that you have provided proper server names in endpoints . Try to ping your deployment server if you can ping it.  Share the config file for the client too.

Comment: How can you possibly mark this as the answer... Your own comment denies it.